# EF 4.1 RC Run SQL statement

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I would like to run a SQL statement using CF. But the CF is not fixing related entities. How can I achieve this?
Can I use DbConnection to manually run my statement and fix related entities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute multile SQL statements to get relations as well.

```
var entity = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntity>("SELECT ...");
var relatedEntities = context.Database.SqlQuery<MyRelatedEntity>(
    "SELECT ... WHERE EntityId = @id", new SqlParemater("id", entity.Id));
```

If you use `DbConnection` and execute that SQL as `DbCommand` you will have to use `DbDataReader` and create entities in the old ADO.NET way. No mapping will be done for you.